# How to receive image bytearray from JSON in Web API 2

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api2

My android Application send name and image from multipartbuilder,

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://" + getString(R.string.host_ip) + "/test/api/Names/");

        MultipartEntityBuilder Entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        Entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        Entity.addPart("FirstName", new StringBody(editText.getText().toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        Entity.addBinaryBody("Image", getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"));


        HttpEntity entity = Entity.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);


        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

it successfully make POST request and it hits breakpoint in Controller, but the item is null, also in intellitrace, it throws:

Exception:Caught: "Unable to translate bytes [89] at index 194 from specified code page to Unicode." (System.Text.DecoderFallbackException)
A System.Text.DecoderFallbackException was caught: "Unable to translate bytes [89] at index 194 from specified code page to Unicode."

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostinsName(Names item)
    {
        item = repositry.Add(item);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Names>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.ID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Names
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public byte[] image { get; set; }
}
```

using Android Studio, Visual Studio 2013 Web Api 2 with c#
Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20228267/1415295 this solve my problem 75%

Comment: What's the remaining 25% of the problem?

Comment: converting to base64 and retrieving from base64 string causes bad quality picture in result, thats another qs but if u can help than it will be great..

Comment: Have you tested the image before conversion?  Then have you taken the base64 string and run it through some other converter (there are some online) and tested that image?  It seems you need to narrow down where the problem is.